# Removed Spotlight, now there's a gap I can't get rid of

Tags: spotlight, menu-bar

I disabled and removed spotlight from my menubar to save performance and space. Now except for saving some space, I have a gap in my menu-bar I'd like to get rid of:

[image: Screenshot of the gap]

Anyone an idea how to get it away?

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: Log off and log back in.

Comment: Restarting does not help. Therefore logging off and back in does not work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, revert whatever you did to remove it. Then, run the following commands in Terminal.app:

```
$ sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/
$ killall SystemUIServer
```

(The `$` only represents the prompt and should not be typed.)

What I get:
[image: Spotlight removed]

To get Spotlight back, enter the following commands:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/
$ killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: You're welcome.

I forgot one thing: If you "repair permissions", it'll also revert this hack.

Answer (score 1):

Logging out and back in (or restarting your computer) will fix the problem, but you might be able to fix it simply by <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-dragging one of the icons next to it.  Holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd> will let you move *some* of the icons around, and I've found that sometimes, moving one will re-arrange the others to fill any gaps that may have appeared.

This will also help you put them in an order that you like best.

Comment: Does not help :(

Comment: @Nils What method did you use to remove the icon?  If you used a "hack-y" method, you may just have removed the icon resource and not told OS X to release the space that it reserves for it.